# Stripe inactive subscription as Payment Intent

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have been following this guide to create a subscription service using Stripe's API:

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements#create-subscription

Everything works, however as soon as the payment element is loaded, an inactive subscription is created due to the payment intent. As stated in the guide:

> At this point the Subscription is inactive and awaiting payment

If the payment is successful, what is returned is the `payment intent`,
`payment intent client secret`, and `redirect status` status.

So here are my issues:

1. It seems terribly illogical to create an inactive subscription for every customer that visits the payment element. Let's say hypothetically I had the payment element on my landing page, my Stripe would be overwhelmed with inactive subscriptions. Even if the user reloads/revisits the payment page a new subscription is created. It just seems messy.
2. I want to store the active subscription ID in a database and only allow a user to subscribe once. But the response doesn't return the subscription ID, it only retuns the payment intent stuff listed above.

This just seems like not the best way to do this, am I doing something wrong?

Is there a way to get the active subscription ID with the success response?

AND/OR

Is there a way to initialize the payment element with a payment intent before creating the subscription, and then create the subscription after success?

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, the subscription is in `incomplete` status because it requires a payment method to pay its first invoice so that it can transition to `active` status. So if you want to make a subscription `active` upon creation, you need to specify a [default_payment_method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=python#create_subscription-default_payment_method) during creation.

You can use the [SetupIntent API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/setup-intents) to collect a payment_method.

1. Create a customer
2. Create a SetupIntent with the customer
3. Use the SetupIntent's client_secret to render the PaymentElement
4. Call [stripe.confirmSetup](https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/confirm_setup) to confirm the SetupIntent so that the collected payment_method is attached to the customer

Now, you can pass the earlier collected payment_method as the `default_payment_method` when creating a subscription, and the resulting subscription will become `active` if the first invoice is paid successfully with the `default_payment_method`. You don't need to use PaymentElement in this step anymore because you already collected a payment_method through SetupIntent.